# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql' when trying to create an instance of a generic type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, visual-studio-2012

We have a unit test project for testing SQL Server stored procedures in VS2012. I'm trying to write a generic method that builds and populates a `TestCondition` object:

```
public static T CreateTestCondition<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> propertyDelegate, object value)
    where T : TestCondition, new()
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)propertyDelegate.Body;
    string propertyName = expression.Member.Name;

    T condition = new T();
    typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(condition, value);

    return condition;
}
```

And this is how the method is called:

```
NotEmptyResultSetCondition condition =
      CreateTestCondition((NotEmptyResultSetCondition x) => x.ResultSet, 1);
```

When I run this, I get the following exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=10.3.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On line `T condition = new T()`. If I try to do something like

`NotEmptyResultSetCondition condition = new NotEmptyResultSetCondition();`

It works fine, however for some reason I can't create an instance using the generic type even though when I look `T` at runtime it has a fully qualified type name. I also tried to use the `Activator` class and pass in the full assembly and type names seperately, but that doesn't work either (which I'd be surprised if it did). Any idea why VS can't find the assembly?